# Ansible: Interate over tree structure

Tags: python, loops, tree, ansible

**I want iterate over tree structure.**

How to iterate over level1 and level2 only ? ( I want to see corelation like below shown between name and level0 )

Maybe the structure is wrong ? ( json | list of dict or other ?)

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   directories:
    - name: DIR1
      level0:
       - name: SUBDIR1
         level1:
           - name: SUBDIR11
             level2:
              - name: SUBDIR111
              - name: SUBDIR112
           - name: SUBDIR12
             level2:
              - name: SUBDIR121
              - name: SUBDIR122
       - name: SUBDIR2
       - name: SUBDIR3
    - name: DIR2
      level0:
       - name: SUBDIR1
       - name: SUBDIR2
       - name: SUBDIR3

  tasks:
  - name: Debug level0
    debug:
      msg: "DIR {{item.0.name}} Subdir {{item.1.name}}"
    loop: "{{ directories | subelements('level0') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four lists nested. Therefor 2 nested loops both with subelements are needed. For example, with the included task from the file `loop-item.yml`

```
shell> cat loop-item.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ outer_item.0.name }} {{ outer_item.1.name }} {{ item.0.name }} {{ item.1.name }}"
  loop: "{{ outer_item.1.level1|default([])|subelements('level2') }}"
```

the task

```
  - include_tasks: loop-item.yml
    loop: "{{ directories|subelements('level0') }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: outer_item
```

gives the decomposition of the nested lists

```
    "msg": "DIR1 SUBDIR1 SUBDIR11 SUBDIR111"
    "msg": "DIR1 SUBDIR1 SUBDIR11 SUBDIR112"
    "msg": "DIR1 SUBDIR1 SUBDIR12 SUBDIR121"
    "msg": "DIR1 SUBDIR1 SUBDIR12 SUBDIR122"
```

---

> Q: *"Maybe the structure is wrong ? ( json | list of dict or other ?)"*

A: The structure is fine. It's possible to iterate lists only. Any other structure would have to be transformed into a list anyway.